# No desktop short cut for Blender 2.8

Tags: installation

I just installed the Blender 2.8 beta. It did not create a shortcut. How can I create a short cut on the desktop?

Comment: Linux, or Windows?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's OS-related and not Blender-related.

Comment: This is not a community for this.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows right click the exe. file (what you click to open Blender). From drop down menu find "send to". With the pointer on "send to" you will see "desktop (create shortcut)"... click it.
In Linux (Debian derivative in my case) it is much the same.  Right click the file in the folder where the Blender exe. file is and "send to" / desktop (create link).  Easy peasie.

Comment: Thank you for answering and sorry to post in wrong forum.

Answer (score 2):

#### Installing/Upgrading Blender on Linux (Debian 12):

- Download/unzip Blender to desired location. I use the `/usr/share` directory
- Once unzipped, move **blender.desktop** file to **applications** directory via:
   `$: sudo mv /path/to/blender.desktop /usr/share/applications`
- From there, edit the `blender.desktop` file and give it the location of Blender & the icon. From the command line use:
   `$: sudo gedit blender.desktop`
- Scroll down to find these two lines: 
  `Exec=blender %f`
  `Icon=blender`
- Edit to reflect Blender's new location: 
  `Exec=/path/to/blender %f`
  `Icon=/path/to/blender.svg`
- Save `blender.desktop` file and restart your machine.
- Double-click your blender executable to launch Blender.
- Icon should now display at bottom or side of Desktop, right-click the icon to pin it.

Comment: this is truly absurd. Not being able to easily add executables to desktop and sidebar is an unfathomably huge blunder in ubuntu.  they should stop every single feature and release until they get this. it is as basic as being able to open a file manager and find files.