# Q: Blender 2.8 desktop shortcut doesn't work

Tags: linux

After downloading 2.8 on Linux Mint, the `blender.desktop` shortcut doesn't open the application; it simply displays "There was an error launching the application". Running the executable directly works without any flaws.

Comment: Is the path in the .desktop correct?

Comment: Yes, the executable is in the same folder and the name is correct.

Comment: Be sure the .desktop file refers to `/dir/to/blender` and not `/dir/to/Blender`

Comment: the file uses `exec=blender`, `blender` is in the exact same directory.

Answer (score 1):

In the *blender.desktop* file, scroll down to find these two lines:
`Exec=blender %f`
`Icon=blender`

Edit them to reflect Blender's location on your machine:
`Exec=/usr/share/blender-YOUR-VERSION-OF-BLENDER/blender %f`
`Icon=/usr/share/blender-YOUR-VERSION-OF-BLENDER/blender.svg`

Full process outlined [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/199552/24959).